# How to set icons for a new document type on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm building an app that reads its own proprietary file types. I've been trying to set the icon for the new document type so that when these documents are presented outside of the app, specifically on the Dropbox app, they would have a dedicated icon.
I exported a new UTI and also defined a Document Type that my app handles via Xcode. I made sure to specify icons of the appropriate sizes, as specified in 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The link is dead.